# Replace a part of text with an element

Tags: javascript, html

I was creating a function with JavaScript. The basic motive of the function was to replace **some** text of an element with *an element* . I wanted to change the *text emoticon* with *image of the emoticon*. But that didn't happen.

I was successful in changing the **some** part of text, but the image didn't show up - the code for the image did.

*e.g.:*

[image: Look the Image here]

My code:

```
function comment_emo_change() {
    var comment_content = document.getElementsByClassName("comment_text");
    for (i = 0; i < comment_content.length; i++) {
        var con_cmo = comment_content[i].textContent;
        var new_con_cmo = con_cmo.replace(":)", "<img src='/scripts/smiley-emocone.gif' class='smiley-emocone'></img>");
        comment_content[i].textContent = new_con_cmo;
    }
}
comment_emo_change();
```

I want the image to appear instead of its code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`.

Comment: Use `comment_content[i].innerHTML = new_con_cmo;` at the end of your function instead of `comment_content[i].textcontent = new_con_cmo;`

Comment: You can't assign HTML to `textContent`, it will be output as plain text.

Comment: I got that. But, i want to know why `innerHTML` did work and `textContent` didn't.

Comment: Because textContent only introduce plain text. innerHTML render the string with html entities

Comment: I don't know how to explain it in another way. Your image will not be HTML, but instead text. So that won't work for what you want.

Comment: Manuel Rodriguez Gil answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Global Variables
var i = con_cmo = new_con_cmo = null;
// Core
function comment_emo_change() {
   var comment_content = document.getElementsByClassName('comment_text');
   for (i = 0; i < comment_content.length; i++) {
       con_cmo = comment_content[i].innerHTML;
        new_con_cmo = con_cmo.replace(':)', '<img src="/scripts/smiley-emocone.gif" class="smiley-emocone"/>');
        comment_content[i].innerHTML = new_con_cmo;
   }
}
// Function call
comment_emo_change();
```

This worked for me. Hope this works for you as well!